# MongoDB - change value where key matches

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a user, and inside I keep a list of items he has rated.

```
> db.users.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5321985944aebf2ca6f2075f"),
    "ratings" : [
        {
            "532192d344aebf2ca6f2075e" : 0
        },
        {
            "532199d144aebf2ca6f20760" : 1
        }
    ],
    "email" : "joe@example.com",
    "name" : "Joe Bloggs"
}
```

The ratings are in the form:

```
{ item_id : <score> }
```

The problem is, if a user rates the same item twice (with a different rating), instead of replacing the old one, it will add the new element to the array.

I am using `$addToSet` to avoid duplicates, but I would like to replace an old rating.

I'm currently doing this in a convoluted way, is there anything simpler? (I'm using Java but it doesn't matter if the solution doesn't.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably not the best schema design for a number of reasons. You would be better served by this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5321985944aebf2ca6f2075f"),
    "ratings" : [
        {
            id: "532192d344aebf2ca6f2075e", score: 0
        },
        {
            id: "532199d144aebf2ca6f20760", score: 1
        }
    ],
    "email" : "joe@example.com",
    "name" : "Joe Bloggs"
}
```

At least in that way you can match on the `id` of the element of the array.

To your problem though. [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) is a nice convenience, but of course does not solve your issue. It still can be used, but if you want to **add** to a "score" like this then you would have to use (with the new model of course):

```js
var count = db.collection.find({
  "_id" : ObjectId("5321985944aebf2ca6f2075f"),
  "ratings.id": "532192d344aebf2ca6f2075e" 
}).count();

if ( count != 0 ) {
   db.collection.update(
       {
           "_id" : ObjectId("5321985944aebf2ca6f2075f"),
           "ratings.id": "532192d344aebf2ca6f2075e" 
       },
       {
           "$inc": { "ratings.$.score": 1 }
       }
   );
} else {
    db.collection.update(
       {
           "_id" : ObjectId("5321985944aebf2ca6f2075f"),
           "ratings.id": "532192d344aebf2ca6f2075e" 
       },
       {
           "$push": {
               "id": newId,
               "score": newScore
           }
       }
    );
}
```

Or whatever equivalent in your implementation language.

So [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) becomes a bit redundant in your case, as you need to check to decide whether you [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) or [$inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) as your case may be. More involved, but it's the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)?

```
db.users.update({"email":"joe@example.com"}, {$set:{"ratings.item_id":5}})
```

This way, if no earlier rating was present, a new one will be added.  If it's already present, it will be updated.

Note: You'll need to replace "item_id" with the actual item id from your client.

Comment: Actually, reading the question, it's a bit more involved. $set may be right, or $inc even but this is trying to maintain a unique **set** of items that do not duplicate.

Comment: I think this would work, if the only way ratings are ever added/updated in a document are using $set. Then there wouldn't be any duplicates.

Comment: Read the answer I supplied as well as reading the question again and you should see where this falls short. Which is the only reason I left you the comment. So you can understand this.